# Where to find Full Stacked Column Chart where there are three colors in the column. And the Color is changed with the value of second?

Tags: laravel, charts

I want a Full Stacked Column Chart where there are three colors in the column. And the Color is changed with the value of a field. Just like the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbmKZ.jpg)
I search too much on the web but doesn't get it.
Can anyone help me about it. I use laravel for backend.

Comment: you can use a [stacked column chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#stacked-column-charts)...